# How do I remove a phantom printer (driver)?

Tags: printing, cups-lpd

When I try to print from any app, two printers show up, the working CUPS printer named "Canon_MX920_series" and a phantom "MX920 series", left over from a botched printer install attempt a year ago that I can't recall any details of.  I want to delete "MX920 series", but when I go to the CUPS management webpage, it only shows the "Canon_MX920_series".

I have seen suggestions to go to "Applications - system settings - printers", but I don't have that exact menu structure (maybe because this is Mythbuntu?) and there is no "printers" anywhere in my Applications menu.  Maybe all I need is the command that opens the printers app?

Edit:  I found the system-config-printer command.  When I run it, the GUI just shows the valid printer, not the phantom.  Likewise for lpstat...